# Animated banner ads (tweenlite.js) that take all CPU from phaser games site

Tags: javascript, adsense, phaser-framework, gsap

How to make the preferred content of my games web page (my own phaser games) to run faster than some 3rd party banner ads that are shown on the page? The ads make my game very slow.

Note: problem appears mostly in Firefox, not Chrome.

[image: browser hangs badly when phaser game page has 3rd party google banner ads]

Comment: Can you make the ad dismissable and remove it from the DOM?

Comment: ... maybe you could replace the `window.requestAnimationFrame` before you load up google's code? In your method you would "skip" calling the callback every so often. I guess then the problem is phaser would also be slowed - presumably you'd have to roll your own render-loop that uses the _real_ requestAnimationFrame directly.

Comment: these ads banners appear outside the game itself, so cannot remove these

Comment: That looks totally unrelated to TweenLite (GSAP) - there's a drawTextPlate() function in TextPlate.js that's eating up the resources. Very tough to troubleshoot blind, but that particular ad seems to contain a function that's CPU-intensive.

Comment: Hello inside drawTextPlate() there seem to be "h.dispatchEvent Tweenlite taking 100% from CPU in drawTextPlate.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, but it sure sounds like it has nothing to do with TweenLite. It's some other code in drawTextPlate(). I don't know what "h" is, but if it's GSAP's ticker, there's no way that's eating up a bunch of resources. Again, tough to troubleshoot blind.

Comment: Why do you just set your Add provider preferences to not allow Animated adds so they then should not be effecting your render loop.

Comment: well there are no any other animated ads causing any issues, so why should I remove all animated ads and remove remarkable income..